# how to calculate the limit as $\lim_{s \to 0 }$ of this large equation?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am having a hard time calculating this limit:

$$\lim_{s \to 0 } \frac{-R_{4}}{R_{3}}\frac{sC_{2}\frac{R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{4}}\frac{R_{5}+R_{6}}{R_{6}} }  {\frac{s^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}}{R_{6}} +sC_{2}R_{2}\frac{R_{3}} {R_{3}+R_{4}} \frac{R_{5}+R_{6}}{R_{6}}   +1}$$

the expected limit result should be 0.

How I did it:

- I took the elements with the highest grade

$$\stackrel{HG}{=} \lim_{s \to \infty } \frac{sC_{2}\frac{R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{4}}\frac{R_{5}+R_{6}}{R_{6}} } {\frac{s^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}}{R_{6}}}$$

- replaced with $0$

$$ \lim_{s \to 0}  = \frac{0}{0^2}$$

- and this is where something is wrong.

**EDIT**

SOmething else I tried but am not sure is allowed in math:

$$ \lim_{s \to 0 } \frac{sC_{2}{R_{3}}R_{2}{R_{5}+R_{6}} } {{s^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}(R_{3}+R_{4})}} \frac{{s^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}(R_{3}+R_{4})}}{{s^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}(R_{3}+R_{4})}}$$

$$\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{s^3C_{1}(C_{2})^2R_{1}(R_{2})^2R_{3}R_{5}(R_{5}+R_{6})(R_{3}+R_{4})}{(s^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}(R_{3}+R_{4}))^2}$$

$$\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{s^3C_{1}(C_{2})^2R_{1}(R_{2})^2R_{3}R_{5}(R_{5}+R_{6})(R_{3}+R_{4})}{s^2(C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}(R_{3}+R_{4}))^2}$$

$$\lim_{s \to 0} \frac{s^3}{s^2}$$

$$\lim_{s \to 0} s$$
$$0$$

Comment: Do the R's and C's depend on $s$? If not, this is a fairly simple limit of a rational function.

Comment: Let $(a_n), (b_n)$ be two convergent sequences then
$$\lim a_n+b_n=\lim a_n + \lim b_n$$
$$\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = \frac{\lim a_n}{  \lim b_n}, ~b_n \neq0, ~\lim b_n \neq 0$$
$$\lim a_n b_n=\lim a_n  \lim b_n$$

Use this to move the limit.

Comment: @giobrach the R's and C's are constants. Have u had a look at my edit? :)

Comment: @MarvinF. have u had a look at my edit? Is this move "legal" in math?

Comment: @J.Doe I'm not sure what you did there. Essentially it is
$$\lim \frac{x}{x^2+x+1}=\frac{\lim x}{\lim x^2 + \lim x + \lim 1} = \frac{0}{0+0+1}=\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are making it much more complicated than necessary.

As a first step, *compute* the expression at the given point.

$$\frac{-R_{4}}{R_{3}}\frac{0C_{2}\frac{R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{4}}\frac{R_{5}+R_{6}}{R_{6}} }  {\frac{0^2C_{1}C_{2}R_{1}R_{2}R_{5}}{R_{6}} +0C_{2}R_{2}\frac{R_{3}} {R_{3}+R_{4}} \frac{R_{5}+R_{6}}{R_{6}}   +1}=\frac{-R_{4}}{R_{3}}\frac01=0.$$

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation! Altough it is too complicated: are my overly complex calculations correct? I mean is it mathematically correct to put the s^2 outside of the brackets in the denominator?

Comment: @J.Doe: it's harmful introducing indeterminacy where there is none.

Comment: This is the correct solution! I deleted my answer. Sorry @J.Doe

Comment: @giobrach why was yours incorrect? it seemed perfeclty legit as well at first sight...

Comment: Direct substitution of $s=0$ was not an issue because of the $+1$ factor in the denominator. So you'd have $0/1 = 0$ as in the answer above